# Samba reporting not enough free space but getting zero bytes folder after access with MAC system

Tags: linux, macos, centos7, redhat, samba

I have configured the Samba server on CentOS 7 and assigned 1GB quota to a shared directory. When I am accessing it from the Mac system and trying to copy approx 2GB file then getting error of having a lower amount of space, it is leaving the same filename of zero bytes in the destination directory.

Please suggest, how can I avoid this unwanted zero byte file in the destination directory?

Comment: Do you mean you are having trouble fitting a 2GB file in a 1GB space?

Comment: No, I am facing an issue like when server is giving error as lower amount of space then why MAC system is leaving the same filename of zero bytes in the destination directory.